# p:selectOneMenu with relative width stretches out when resizing browser

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

When I increase browser's window size (e.g. changing resolutions from 1024x768 to 1920x1080), the `<p:selectOneMenu>` becomes from this:

[image: before 1024x768]

to this:

[image: after]

I figured out that the problem arises when I add a relative width to the component, e.g:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... style="width: 30%;">
```

How can I remove the unnecessary space? I am using PrimeFaces 3.3.1

Comment: When you said "combobox", do you actually mean `<p:selectOneMenu>`? Well, I can't reproduce it using Chrome 24 / FireFox 18 / IE9 on their own [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf). Can you? Please tell about all the browsers which you tried. Please also note that a "combobox" is an editable dropdown, while you perhaps actually meant to say "dropdown".

Comment: Yes, I mean `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Acctually I figured out that the problem arise when I add relative width in the component - e.g.  `<p:selectOneMenu ... style="width: 30%;">` and the behavior is the same in all browsers that you mentioned. I will edit original post.

Comment: I found out that the problem is in the label component of selectOneMenu. It gets fixed width: `<label ... style="135px">` when primefaces generates html. Any help how to disable or override this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the selectonemenu to stretch while resizing or by its text use

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Perfectly worked for me.